# Need explanation on strange behavior of Simplify under given assumption

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

This is quite surprising to me.

```
Simplify[a == b, {a == {1}, b == {1}}]
```

> ```
> a == b
> ```

does not evaluate the equality, while

```
Simplify[a == b, {a == 1, b == 1}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

does. What is the explanation?

Another one:

```
Simplify[a/b == e/f, {a/b == c/d, c/d == e/f}]
```

> ```
> a/b == e/f
> ```

Comment: Even FullSimplify can't do this.
But I found this:
In[] Simplify[a == b, {a == c[{1}], b == c[{1}]}]
Out[] True

Comment: Perhaps an even more succinct example is comparing `Simplify[a, a == {1}]` to `Simplify[a, a == 1]`

Comment: List equality/simplification vs number equality/simplification, interesting.

Comment: But isn't this a matter of `{1}` not being "more simple" than `a`? `Simplify` does what it says: it *simplifies* an expression according to some "aesthetic". One thing that it does is to minimize the `LeafCount` of the expression, and `LeafCount@a` is `1` whereas `LeafCount@{1}` is `2`. @JasonB.

Comment: @JasonB and OP: I recommend putting those examples into the original post, because especially the OP's version with `c[{1}]` is confusing (although I think my previous comment accounts for JasonB's example and it might account for the OP's).

Comment: @march: For the version with c[{1}], I'm trying to say that it looks harder to simplify. How's about the last one? It looks simple but fails to bridge c/d. Quite disappointed.

Comment: As march says, the most likely explanation is that `Simplify` (and `FullSimplify`) mostly try to simplify expressions "locally" and that the transformation of `a` into `{1}` complicates the expression.  Similarly in your last example, replacing `c/d` by `c d` makes `Simplify` find the answer.